# What is the difference between when my proposed edits being approved and 'revised'?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I'm new and I didn't understand the difference.

Comment: You mean the two proposed edits I just approved? [1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/6783/revisions) [2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/24565/revisions)

Comment: Yes, those are both examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested edits that are improved on simply result in multiple revisions - one for the initial suggestion, and one for the improver. As such, if there are revisions made to your proposed edit, you can simply see what changes were made by comparing your revision to the one immediately following it.

The actual content of your own edit submission will always be unaltered in itself, all that can be done is to simply "make a subsequent edit".

Comment: I think that I'm getting closer to understanding the difference between 'approved' and 'revised', but I'm not 100% there yet.  I know that the latter follows the former, but I don't get why there is a separation?  Is this because I can't revise directly myself, yet?

Comment: That's exactly the case. At 2000 reputation, users can freely edit posts without needing to have those "suggested edits" be approved. Instead, they're just full fledged edits. Until then, your edits need to be approved first. Once they *are* approved, though, they are basically the same as a normal edit.